# Postfix delivery based on headers

Tags: email, postfix, filter, smtp-headers

I need to filter email delivery in Postfix based on a specific header.

Lets have the following example:

There's some PHP script that will dispatch emails to the local MTA (postfix). These emails contain a specific custom header (for example sake, X-EMAIL-TYPE) that will have one of 3 values:

- Bulk
- Transactional
- Autoreply

I need to dispatch emails to different SMTP servers based on the X-EMAIL-TYPE header.

Is this possible in Postfix? If yes, how can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Email routing is based on recipient's domain and not on an individual header. You need to refine your question by examples.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this helps you but i think you can do it with header check.s
Just luck in the file where your configs are.(/etc/postfix/header_checks). I only used this to reject mails that contain some character encodings but i think it can be done from there.